# Powermock whenNew doesn't work on simple DTO

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock, powermockito

I know that is stupid question, but I can't understand why it so.
I have test code with tests, where I trying to understand how Powermockito.whenNew method works.

Simple DTO User.class

```
public class User {

    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Simple test

```
package ru.nikita.security.models;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNull;

@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({User.class})
class UserTest {

    @Test
    void getId() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(User.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(null);
        User user = new User();

        assertNull(user);
    }
}
```

Gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '1.7.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito', version: '1.7.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.10.19'
}
```

I don't understand why when I create new user it create simple new object.

Comment: Bytecode manipulation.

Comment: @Antoniossss I'm sorry I didn't understand what you meant

Comment: you are not using powermokito here at all, create a class which has a method which create new User object inside it, mock and perform some operation on that in that case you will get what you want, here you are manually creating User object checking it